# Swift audio speech - how to pause between words?

Tags: swift3, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to speak one or more words. I want to introduce a pause between these words.  For example: "Let's Dance"

The code I'm playing with is:

```
speechString = "Say " + substring[0]
        utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: speechString!)
        utterance.rate = 0.4
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "el-GR")
        
        synth.pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.word)
        synth.speak(utterance)
            sleep(2)
        synth.continueSpeaking()
)
```

I hear the words but no pause.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, the solution is to insert a comma or two like:

```
speechString = "Say,, " + substring[0]
```